# How to use the NEPacketTunnelProvider in an ipv6 environment

Tags: ios, swift, networkextension

My application implements an `IPv4` tunnel using `NEPacketTunnelProvider`. The tunneling system works perfect but it doesn’t work when it is in the IPv6.

I am trying to make my `VPN` app adapt to `ipv6` environment, but I don't know how to start, please tell me how to do.

Here's my code:

```
let newSettings = NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings(tunnelRemoteAddress: "127.0.0.1")
let ip = "32.432.53.1"
let subnet = "10.3.21.1"
newSettings.ipv4Settings = NEIPv4Settings(addresses: [ip], subnetMasks: [subnet])
newSettings.mtu = 1432
newSettings.ipv4Settings?.includedRoutes = [NEIPv4Route.default()]
newSettings.ipv6Settings?.includedRoutes = [NEIPv6Route.default()]
newSettings.dnsSettings = NEDNSSettings(servers: ["8.8.8.8"])
```

```
let endPoint = NWHostEndpoint(hostname: "12.432.55.22", port: 9090)
var session = self.createUDPSession(to: endPoint, from: nil)

self.session?.writeDatagram(newData, completionHandler: { (error) in

})
self.session?.setReadHandler({ (newPackets: [Data]?, error: Error?) -> Void in

}, maxDatagrams: NSIntegerMax)
```

Answer (score 0):

`newSettings.ipv4Settings = NEIPv4Settings(addresses: [ip], subnetMasks: [subnet])`
there is only a `ipv4Settings` for the newSettings

You should add these lines:

```
let ipv6Settings = NEIPv6Settings.init(addresses: ["fe80:1ca8:5ee3:4d6d:aaf5"], networkPrefixLengths: [64])
newSettings.ipv6Settings = ipv6Settings
```

But my demo's UDPSession `setReadHandler` is not involved